# flutter The argument type 'FadeInImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?

Tags: flutter, dart

guys any way to put a fadeInImage as a background of a cicrle avatar? i'm trying but i get this compiler error

```
The argument type 'FadeInImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'
```

this is my circle avatar

```
child: Obx(() {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        controller.urlImagem.value.toString(),
                      ),
                      maxRadius: 100,
                    );
                  }),
```

I want to put this code but this error appears to me at the top

```
child: Obx(() {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      
                      backgroundImage: controller.urlImagem.value.isNotEmpty ? FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(placeholder: kTransparentImage, image: controller.urlImagem.value) : null,
                      maxRadius: 100,
                    );
                  }),
                ),
```

Comment: What's the value of `kTransparentImage` ?

Comment: is a package that gives me a transparent image https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same question since the Flutter example didn't mention anything else about it. The solution came from the [transparent_image](https://github.com/brianegan/transparent_image) GitHub repo, which is to wrap `kTransparentImage` in a `MemoryImage`:

```
MemoryImage(kTransparentImage);
```

From the documentation `MemoryImage` 'Creates an object that decodes a Uint8List buffer as an image.'

Comment: Thanx my friend,

Comment: You should mark my answer as the correct answer if it helped you so the question gets closed :)